# SwiftUI update State on Navigation Action

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, list, swiftui

I am using a Navigation View in my SwiftUI Mac OSX app. I have having a List view to select Persons, and then display their attributes in PersonDetail. It is working fine. However, I am sending a State to a Binding in `PersonDetail View`.

That is working fine, however everytime a new row is clicked, I want to reset my State `s_selectedView` to `0` again.

Is there an event for NavigationView updates? I tried using a `onAppear()` event in my PersonDetail view, however that is only called once. The only option I see is pushing my State towards my `List` and then change it on the `tapGesture` of the Table View.

That is my Navigation View code:

```
  NavigationView {
    PersonList(selectedPerson: $selectedPerson)

    if selectedPerson != nil {
        PersonDetail(person: selectedPerson!, s_currentView: self.$s_selectedView)
        //Here I would need a event, for appear / update
        //.onAppear
        //{
            //only called once 
        //}

    }
  }
```

This is my binding in the same view above:

```
@State var s_selectedView : Int = 0
```

I want to reset that variable to 0, whenever a new item was pressed in the list.

**TL:DR**

Is there a equivalent function like `onAppear` only for `update` for a state? The problem is that my view is not appearing again (`onAppear` is not getting called), just the data is changing due to `@State` event. How can I catch that event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like the following - use proxy binding to selected person and once selected person changed reset your state:

(scratchy - not tested)

```
NavigationView {
    PersonList(selectedPerson: Binding<Type_Of_Selected_Person>(get: {
            self.selectedPerson
        }, set: {
            self.selectedPerson = $0
            self.s_selectedView = 0
        }))
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help @Asperi It works indeed perfect. That's the perfect answer here..